# Low volume and bass on Windows 10 after dual-booting Ubuntu

Tags: windows-10, audio, ubuntu-18.04

I installed Ubuntu 18.04 alongside Windows 10 (same disk but different partitions, eg. dual-boot) and now when I'm listening to music from Youtube on Windows, I have noticed that even maximum volume is far lower than it used to be, and there is almost no bass. My headset is wired version of Logitech PRO X. I tried uninstalling it from Device Manager and installed Logitech G HUB software, but nothing seems to help. On Ubuntu sound and bass works fine. Any advise would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Update BIOS and update/reinstall the Audio driver

Comment: @John I just did that but the latest available BIOS version for my laptop was released in 2012... it might be time to upgrade.